# How to force OpenLayers to load source?

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

I have noticed that **OpenLayers** will not "load" **source** unless it is assigned to a **layer** which is assigned to **map**.

This code does `console.log()` with number of **features** in a KML layer:

```js
const layer = new Heatmap({
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: file,
    format: new KML({
      extractStyles: false,
    }),
  }),
});

layer.getSource().on('change', function (evt: any) {
  var source = evt.target;
  if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
    var numFeatures = source.getFeatures().length;
    console.log('Count after change: ' + numFeatures);
  }
});

this.map.addLayer(layer);
```

If I remove this line:

```js
this.map.addLayer(layer);
```

it doesn't output anything. I have a feeling that **OpenLayers** ignores it as it is not used. Is there a way to force **OpenLayers** to load it?

(context - I would like to merge **features** coming from multiple **sources** into one thus I don't want to directly load them onto the **map**. I'd like them to load so I can get **features** and then merge these **features** into one array and then display this array on the **map**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine features from multiple files and formats by fetching the urls and using the format's `readFeatures()` method

```
const vectorSource = new VectorSource();
const layer = new  Heatmap({
  source: vectorSource,
});

function loadFromUrl (url, format) {
  fetch(url).then(function (response) {
    response.text().then(function (result) {
      vectorSouce.addFeatures(
        format.readFeatures(result, {
          dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
          featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection(),
        })
      }
    });
}

loadFromUrl(kmlFile, new KML({extractStyles: false}));
loadFromUrl(geojsonFile, new GeoJSON());
```